# operator== compiler error when using STL std::remove iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

`vec` is `std::vector<std::string>` type. I'm trying to remove strings which not equal to `query`.

> ```
>     Compare compare(0, i, query);
>     vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare));
> ```

This is my Functor:

> ```
> class Compare {
> private:
>     size_t m_from;
>     size_t m_to;
>     std::string m_query;
>
> public:
>     Compare(size_t from, size_t to, std::string& query) : m_from(from), m_to(to), m_query(query)
>     {}
>
>     std::string operator()(std::string s)
>     {
>         
>         if(s.substr(m_from, m_to) != m_query.substr(m_from, m_to))
>         {
>             return s;
>         }
>     } };
> ```

I get this compile error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ and ‘const Compare’)
  241 |  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

I understand that I'm missing `operator==`, but why and where?

Thanks!

Comment: [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) doesn't have a signature that accepts a comparator. Did you mean `std::remove_if` (ibid.)?

Comment: `std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare)` is attempting to remove the object `compare` from your vector.  That's why the compiler is looking for a way to see if any of your strings are equal to a `Compare`.

Comment: You are also using the wrong form of `std::vector::erase`.  Passing **one** parameter (an iterator) will only erase **one** element.  See the duplicate for the correct syntax.